# Domino agents called via XMLHTTPRequest and Agent Manager

Tags: lotus-domino

The help documentation mentions that web agents are handled differently from normal scheduled agents in DOMINO.Web agents are not controlled by the Agent Manager.
I am trying to analyze performance issues in agents being called via numerous XMLHttpRequests.
The called agents normally complete within <1 second.
However in certain cases this may take much longer and a timeout occurs with an Error 500.
Having not found any pattern to this behavior I am wondering whether agents called by the ?Openagent url  are slowed done by the fact that the setting for Max concurrent agents is 3

Additional information:
Number active threads is set to 100

```
HTTPQueueMethod=2
HTTPJVMMaxHeapSize=1024M
HTTPJVMMaxHeapSizeSet=1
```

The Server is adequately sized-physical/settings seem not to be the problem.
am also looking into database views but wanted a clear answer from domain experts concerning the Agent Manager setting.
thanks in advance.

Comment: Max concurrent agents relates to background agents run by agent manager. Web agents are run by Http task.

Comment: Check the "Run web agents and web services concurrently?" setting

Comment: Normunds, thank you for the confirmation.
Per Henrik, this is set to enabled and Timeout to 60seconds.Thanks.

Comment: How long is it taking before they time out?

Comment: what is challenging is that 105000/107000 calls analyzed in the domlog.nsf finish within a second, however the ones that lag over the course of time tend to clubbed together and have a response time of 1,3,6 even upto 155 seconds!! Would it be the views? thanks in advance rgds

Answer (score 0):

There is a setting on the srever document that says how many concurrent web agents can run at a time. If this is set to 1 and you then have a web agent that takes a little time, any other agent that runs afterwards will get stacked up behind the first one (which looks like the issue you are having). I think we have this set to 4. You may have an agent that is running slowly and causing the back-log, or you may need to run more concurrent web agents at one time...